# Sub Query in the from clause in SQL

Tags: sql, subquery

I have two queries and I believe I need to put query number two in the `FROM` statement of query number one could you tell me the best way to do this please?

**QUERY1**

```
SELECT   PARTNO_AUD, PARTNO_ING, COSTSET_AUD, 
        ITEMVER_AUD, PROCNO_AUD, PROCVER_AUD, PROCSTAGE_AUD, 
        ALLITEM_AUD, COSTERR, 
        dbo.SSI_DAVL_FUNC('COSTERR', COSTERR, 'E') AS DESCRIPTION
  FROM  dbo.MBI030
 WHERE  (PARTNO_ING <> N'') 
   AND (PROCNO_AUD <> N'') 
   AND (COSTERR <> N'00')
```

**QUERY2**

```
SELECT  PARTNO_B02PAR, PARTNO_B02COM, 
        QTYOFF / (100 - PSLOSS) * 100 AS QTY
  FROM  dbo.MBB020
```

`PARTNO_AUD` is the same as `PARTNO_B02PAR` and `PARTNO_ING` is the same as `PARTNO_B02COM`

Comment: look at examples for "inner join" or "left outer join".  You probably want "inner join"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming all you want to do is join both the table to see output together

```
SELECT 
    PARTNO_AUD, 
    PARTNO_ING, 
    COSTSET_AUD, 
    ITEMVER_AUD, 
    PROCNO_AUD, 
    PROCVER_AUD, 
    PROCSTAGE_AUD,
    ALLITEM_AUD, 
    COSTERR, 
    dbo.SSI_DAVL_FUNC('COSTERR', COSTERR, 'E') AS DESCRIPTION,
    QTY 
FROM dbo.MBI030 A
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT 
            PARTNO_B02PAR, 
            PARTNO_B02COM, 
            QTYOFF / (100 - PSLOSS) * 100 AS QTY 
        FROM dbo.MBB020) B
    ON A.PARTNO_AUD =B.PARTNO_B02PAR 
         AND A.PARTNO_ING =B.PARTNO_B02COM
WHERE (PARTNO_ING <> N'') 
    AND (PROCNO_AUD <> N'') 
    AND (COSTERR <> N'00')
```

for more info on joins see [This Link about Joins](http://sqlbisam.blogspot.com/2013/12/InnerJoin-LeftOuterJoin-RighOuterJoin-and-FullOuterJoin.html)

Comment: I thought he wanted it the other way around...?

Answer (score 1):

something like:

```
SELECT   PARTNO_AUD, PARTNO_ING, COSTSET_AUD, 
        ITEMVER_AUD, PROCNO_AUD, PROCVER_AUD, PROCSTAGE_AUD, 
        ALLITEM_AUD, COSTERR, 
        dbo.SSI_DAVL_FUNC('COSTERR', COSTERR, 'E') AS DESCRIPTION
  FROM  dbo.MBI030
  inner join dbo.MBB020 on PARTNO_AUD = PARTNO_B02PAR and PARTNO_ING = PARTNO_B02COM
 WHERE  (PARTNO_ING <> N'') 
   AND (PROCNO_AUD <> N'') 
   AND (COSTERR <> N'00')
```

but you may want to change the things you select, you can add:

```
PARTNO_B02PAR, PARTNO_B02COM, 
        QTYOFF / (100 - PSLOSS) * 100 AS QTY
```

if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Well it looks like you want a join. try

```
SELECT  q1.PARTNO_AUD, q1.PARTNO_ING, q1.COSTSET_AUD, 
        q1.ITEMVER_AUD, q1.PROCNO_AUD, q1.PROCVER_AUD, q1.PROCSTAGE_AUD, 
        q1.ALLITEM_AUD, q1.COSTERR, 
        dbo.SSI_DAVL_FUNC('COSTERR', q1.COSTERR, 'E') AS DESCRIPTION, q2.qty
FROM  dbo.MBI030 q1
   INNER JOIN 
   (
       SELECT  PARTNO_B02PAR, PARTNO_B02COM, QTYOFF / (100 - PSLOSS) * 100 AS QTY
       FROM  dbo.MBB020
   ) q2 ON q1.PartNO_AUD = q2.PARTNO_B02PAR AND q1.PARTNO_ING = q2.PARTNO_B02COM
WHERE  (q1.PARTNO_ING <> N'') 
    AND (q1.PROCNO_AUD <> N'') 
    AND (q1.COSTERR <> N'00')
```

The trick is to put the query in parentheses and give it an alias e.g q2.

Works on joins and froms.